# Applying xlsxwriter formulas to a header and some columns

Tags: python, pandas, excel, formatting, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to add some formatting to my Excel output from a Pandas dataframe, but only some of it is working.

I can get my 2 decimal number format to work, but not my column width, date format, header alignment, or autofit.  What am doing wrong here?  I don't get an error, but the formatting I mentioned isn't in the output file when I open it in Excel.

```
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlxsWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(my_path, engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the df to XlsxWriter Excel object.
df_new_db.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1",index=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

num_2deci = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'0.00'})
my_dt = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'m/d/yyyy'})
align_left = workbook.add_format({'align':'left'})
worksheet.set_row(0, None, align_left)
worksheet.set_column('V:V', None, my_dt)
worksheet.set_column('Y:Y', None, num_2deci)
worksheet.set_column('Z:Z', None, num_2deci)
    
worksheet.autofit()
writer.close()
```

Comment: The main reason that you aren't see formatting changes in the header and for date/time columns is that Pandas is already supplying cell formats that override them. See the XlsxWriter docs for explanations and workarounds: [Formatting of the Dataframe output](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-output) and [Formatting of the Dataframe headers](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-headers).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it with a little help from the commentor above (thank you!).  Here's the answer I came up with, in case it can help anyone else:

```
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlxsWriter as the engine. Set the default date column display in this step.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\JoelSilverman\Documents\current_python\excel_merge\output\new_db_rows.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', date_format='m/d/yyyy')

# Convert the df to XlsxWriter Excel object, but drop the header row so that it can be formated below using xlsxwriter
df_new_db.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", startrow=1, header=False,index=False)

# Make the workbook and worksheet
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Define the number format to display: 2 decimal places.
num_2deci = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'0.00'})

# Format the columns using the decimal format
worksheet.set_column("Y:Z", None, num_2deci)

# Format the header with the header format you define
header_format = workbook.add_format({"align": "left"})
for col_num, value in enumerate(df_new_db.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)    

#Autofit the column width to fit the data
worksheet.autofit()
writer.close()
```